# DO loop excluding several values in Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran

How to achieve this in Fortran ?

```
    do i = 1, n Except n/2
```

Is there a convenient way instead of using 'if' in the loop ?

Comment: What's wrong with using a conditional statement inside the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many solutions. Here is one using `cycle`.  It still has an `if` statement in the loop but doesn't have an `if ... end if` block.

```
MyLoop: do i=1, N
   if ( i == N/2 ) cycle MyLoop

   !  use the loop....
   write (*, *) i
end do MyLoop
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have an aversion to conditionals inside loops

```
do i  = 1,(n/2)-1
 ...
end do
do i = (n/2)+1,n
 ...
end do
```

If `n` is, or may be, odd, you'll need to adjust the stop/start indices for the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Place an `if` statement inside a loop

```
do i=1,n
  if (i /= n/2) ...
end do
```

or the `forall` statement  with a mask or the `where` statement are possible to use in certain situations.